# CQWP Audience Targeting Not Working

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, audience-targeting

When using audience targeting on a CQWP it works when you set the target on the web part but when you set the audience on the items in a list it does not display any items.

Does anyone have any experience with this and how it can be overcome?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a SharePoint Audience or an AD Security Group for your groupings of users?

Comment: We are using  a SharePoint audience that was created at the top level in central admin

Comment: Apply Audience Filtering is checked, when you check include items that are not targeted you get all items back

Comment: This is really bugging me because i do this all the time.  I am trying to reproduce the issue and cannot.  So instead of trying things here and there this is what I did with a new Audience and a new webpart. 1. Create a new Audience.  Add the Rules, and Compile the Audience.  2. Added a new CQWP and and checked the two checkboxes in the answer below. 3. Added the Target Audiences existing fiedl to a list, and targeted to my new group.  As expected everything worked fine.  The only thing that wouldn't make my test work is not compiling the audience.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I will take a look at what you are suggesting and let you know

Answer (score 2):

Verify that these two checkboxes are checked in your CQWP properties:

- Apply Audience Filtering
- Include items that are not targeted

I believe that you need the "Apply Audience Filtering" for the item level targeting to work. "Include items that are not targeted" is needed to show things that have no targeting.